# Flask: Make row of Dataframe.to_html() clickable

Tags: python, pandas, flask, jinja2

I have Dataframes generated automatically which shows some data. I want to link each of the rows to a route '/row_details with some of the colums sent as parameters.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    df = get_df()
    return render_template('table.html',  tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')])

@app.route('/row_details')
def row_details():
    column1 = request.args.get('column1')
    column2 = request.args.get('column2')
    #do something with those columns
```

I guess I could generate a new column for the dataframe consisting of the URL + GET parameters, but is there a nicer way to make the whole row clickable?

The important part of the template looks like that right now:

```
{% for table in tables %}
       {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think it is the nicer way to create column with `<a></a>`. Other method would need internal `{% for %}` and `{% if %}` to convert every value in template - so it would be more complex.

Comment: in documentation [to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html#pandas-dataframe-to-html) I found option `formatters=` - I never used it but maybe it could convert values in column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to format columns separatelly - without joining values from two columns - then you can use `formatters` in `to_html()`

You had to use also `escape=False` if you want to put HTML in column. Normally it converts `< >` to `&gt; &lt;`

BTW: I had to also set `'display.max_colwidth'` because it was truncating text in column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'url':[
    'https://stackoverflow.com',
    'https://httpbin.org',
    'https://toscrape.com',
]})

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
result = df.to_html(formatters={'url':lambda x:f'<a href="{x}">{x}</a>'}, escape=False)

print(result)
```

Result:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>url</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">https://stackoverflow.com</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td><a href="https://httpbin.org">https://httpbin.org</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td><a href="https://toscrape.com">https://toscrape.com</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

But if you want to create links using values from two columns then create new column in `DataFrame`.

Eventually you would have to format all in template (without using `to_html`)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'url':[
        'https://stackoverflow.com',
        'https://httpbin.org',
        'https://toscrape.com',
    ],
    'name':[
        'Ask question',
        'Test requests',
        'Learn scraping'
    ]
})
```

and

```
<table>
{% for row in dt.iterrows() %}
    <tr><td><a href="{{ row['url'] }}">{{ row['name'] }}</a></td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```